# Why my ruby on rails application breaks without internet connection on development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just figured out my local application only runs/starts when I have internet connect on my system. **What could possibly cause this?**

**Error I get is when am not connected to internet and I start my server**:

> getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.6'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '3.0.1'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.1'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
#gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '5.0.1'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '2.6.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '0.4.1', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', '9.0.5'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '2.3.0'
  gem 'simple_form', '3.1.0.rc2'
  gem 'redactor-rails', '0.5.0'
  gem 'carrierwave', '0.11.2'
  gem 'mini_magick', '4.5.1'
  gem 'validates_formatting_of', '0.9.0'
  gem 'paper_trail', '4.2.0'
  gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '4.1.1'
  gem 'activejob', '4.2.5.1'
  gem 'i18n-tasks', '~> 0.8.6'
  gem 'social-share-button', '0.2.1'
  gem 'devise', '4.2.0'
  gem 'administrate', '0.2.2'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
  gem 'sass', '3.4.22'
  gem 'font-awesome-sass', '4.6.2'
  gem 'bourbon', '4.2.7'
  gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '2.1.0'
  gem 'figaro', '1.1.1'
  gem 'travis', '1.8.2'
  gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.8.1'
  gem 'ffi', '1.9.14'
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.11'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', '1.2016.6', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Gemifile.lock--Dependencies**

```
DEPENDENCIES
  activejob (= 4.2.5.1)
  administrate (= 0.2.2)
  bootstrap-sass (= 3.3.7)
  bourbon (= 4.2.7)
  byebug (= 9.0.5)
  carrierwave (= 0.11.2)
  coffee-rails (= 4.1.1)
  delayed_job_active_record (= 4.1.1)
  devise (= 4.2.0)
  ffi (= 1.9.14)
  figaro (= 1.1.1)
  font-awesome-sass (= 4.6.2)
  i18n-tasks (~> 0.8.6)
  jbuilder (= 2.6.0)
  jquery-rails (= 4.1.1)
  jquery-turbolinks (= 2.1.0)
  mini_magick (= 4.5.1)
  nokogiri (= 1.6.8.1)
  paper_trail (= 4.2.0)
  pg
  rails (= 4.2.5.1)
  rails_12factor
  redactor-rails (= 0.5.0)
  sass (= 3.4.22)
  sass-rails (= 5.0.6)
  sdoc (= 0.4.1)
  simple_form (= 3.1.0.rc2)
  social-share-button (= 0.2.1)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.11)
  travis (= 1.8.2)
  turbolinks (= 5.0.1)
  tzinfo-data (= 1.2016.6)
  uglifier (= 3.0.1)
  validates_formatting_of (= 0.9.0)
  web-console (= 2.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.11.2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there also a stack trace associated with the error? That would help to narrow down where the failure is happening.

Comment: `social-share-button` seems like the most likely culprit.. However why do you have devise etc in the development group in your gemfile?

Comment: @max, it was completely oversight to have mut all those gems in development group. Nevertheless, removing `devise` still does not make my application work offline.

Comment: Take a look at `/logs/development.log` and post the contents.